# My cookie is set but php can't read it

Tags: php, cookies, fixed

I've been trying to make a cookie autologin, but although the cookie is set, php can't read it. I know it is set because I can see it with Cookie Monster, I don't know what's wrong...
Need help! It's driving me crazy!

The code to set the cookie (I do it before any HTML tag)

```
setcookie("autologin", $_SESSION['user'], time()+5184000, "/");
```

the code to retrieve it:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_COOKIE['autologin'])) {
     $_SESSION['user']=$_COOKIE['autologin'];
}
```

UPDATE: I don't use the code above in the same script. I do login, close the browser, reopen it and try to get the cookie, cookie is in Cookie Monster but php can't see it.

FIX: My problem was I was trying to save a serialized object, $_SESSION['user'], in the cookie, it has been fixed with that:

```
setcookie("autologin", base64_encode($_SESSION['user']), time()+5184000, "/");
```

and retrieving with:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_COOKIE['autologin'])) {
         $_SESSION['user']=base64_decode($_COOKIE['autologin']);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was I was trying to save a serialized object, $_SESSION['user'], in the cookie, it has been fixed with that:

```
setcookie("autologin", base64_encode($_SESSION['user']), time()+5184000, "/");
```

and retrieving with:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_COOKIE['autologin'])) {
         $_SESSION['user']=base64_decode($_COOKIE['autologin']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This cookie will available [on next page loading](http://php.net/setcookie). In this page you can define it yourself.

Comment: I don't use the code in the same script. Read the update to clarify, thanks anyway

Comment: Try to define your domain in setCookie. And check that you using same domains when setting and getting cookies.

Comment: Allright, it's fixed. The problem was serialization, I was trying to save a serialized object in the cookie and, for any reason, it doesn't get it, so I have done serialize and base64_encode, with both, now there's no problem.